# How to get the start location of a span in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get the start location of a span, how can I do it?

For example,

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true">
    I<span id="first">Like</span><span id="second">Apples</span><span id="third">Day</span>
</div>
```

I would like to get the location of "L" in "Like", in this case is 1; if I want Apples' "A", it is 5.

I've tried this

```
$("#first")[0].offsetLeft
```

but what it returns is weird...

I came up with an idea that just get the html then use indexOf() to find the span tag...

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: location as in index of like or offset position?

Comment: Look at this user's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down. They will give you the whole range of selection and text manipulation.

Comment: @Pete the start index of the span in contenteditablee div. In the case of I<span>Like</span><span>Apple</span><span>Day</span>, the index should be 1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Hi Pete, but the link you gave is about array~